# Voting system on NoSQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

Is it possible/reasonable to have a voting system on NoSQL database ?
For example how would be possible to store StackOverflow question into the NoSQL database. 
I can easily imagine almost everything except how the relation will work between question/vote/user. Everything else can be stored in one document, like tags, comments(assuming there are relatively small amount of comments on posts, in my case I will not have comments anyway), user information, etc... but can't imagine how to store user votes as document will become huge. One of the options is that I can have votes stored in separate collection/document, but it will mean that while loading a question there will be a need to send another request to check if the user have voted for a question or not.

Comment: This is not really a question without specific details about your schema, and the type of scale you're dealing with. Even something like MySQL can easily handle millions to hundreds of millions of votes with a properly designed schema.

Comment: @tadman As I said is almost the same as StackOverflow questions just without comments. As for the scale... The web site is not online yet but I expect high traffic that's why I want to have everything ready upfront and avoid future migrations.

Comment: If your site is growing you will *always* have future migrations. Do not over-engineer up front. You have no idea where the pain points are until you stress the system at scale. Build the simplest thing that works, and iterate on that. Incremental design always trumps something that's too complicated for your initial scale, and inadequate and hard to re-engineer when under strain.

Answer (score 1):

A good reference is the MongoDB documentation on [Embedded documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/) vs [Referenced documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/), since those are what you seem to be referring into your question. There's no perfect solution, as both have their trade offs. You just have to make the best decision based on the type of operations/queries and their frequencies that you're expecting to be run on your database.

Honestly, until your database starts getting some serious traffic, the difference between SQL and NoSQL won't matter. Pre optimization can end up doing more harm than good, so I would just go with the one that is easiest to get deployed and you're more comfortable with to begin with.

Comment: thanks for the links they were helpful.

Comment: If there is a good chance that there will be lots of traffic in the future, then to design with scalability in mind from the beginning will save you lots of time in the future.